# Displaying Volume as milliliter/floz

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm hoping someone can help me with this issue that's driving me nuts.

I want to use the formatted() modifier with Measurements so I can get locale specific units, and it's working great for mass and temperature.

I correctly get oz/g and F/C but for volume I'm getting cm3/in3 instead of ml/floz.
I realize that is a Volumetric unit, but It's not the one i want.

```
Text("\(Measurement(value: Double(volume), unit: UnitVolume.milliliters).formatted())")
Text("\(Measurement(value: Double(mass), unit: UnitMass.grams).formatted())")
Text("\(Measurement(value: Double(temp), unit: UnitTemperature.celsius).formatted())")
```

I know I can do this

```
Text("\(Measurement(value: Double(brew.water), unit: UnitVolume.milliliters).formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .asProvided, numberFormatStyle: .number)))")
```

But then I have to figure out the locale myself.
Is there a way to this with the builtins in swiftui?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `converted` and `MeasurementFormatter`

In its simplest form it would look something like

```
struct VolumeSampleView: View {
    let volume = Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitVolume.liters)
    var body: some View {
        Text(volume.converted(to: .milliliters), formatter: MeasurementFormatter())
    }
}
```

But in an `extension` you can add customizations that can be reused and it works similar to `formatted` but allows for iOS 14+.

```
extension Formatter{
    static func measurement(unitOptions: MeasurementFormatter.UnitOptions = .providedUnit, unitStyle: Formatter.UnitStyle = .short, numberStyle: NumberFormatter.Style = .decimal) -> MeasurementFormatter{
        
        let f = MeasurementFormatter()
        f.unitOptions = unitOptions
        f.unitStyle = unitStyle
        
        let nf = NumberFormatter()
        nf.numberStyle = numberStyle
        
        f.numberFormatter = nf
        
        return f
    }
}
```

And then your `View` would evolve to look something like

```
struct VolumeSampleView: View {
    let volume = Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitVolume.liters)
    let mass = Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)
    var body: some View {
        Text(volume.converted(to: .milliliters), formatter: .measurement())
        Text(mass.converted(to: .grams), formatter: .measurement())

    }
}
```

You can also extend `Measurement` itself and add a method that provides the string automatically.

```
extension Measurement{
    func toString(unitOptions: MeasurementFormatter.UnitOptions = .providedUnit, unitStyle: Formatter.UnitStyle = .short, numberStyle: NumberFormatter.Style = .decimal) -> String{
        
        let f = Formatter.measurement(unitOptions: unitOptions, unitStyle: unitStyle, numberStyle: numberStyle)
        return f.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Then you don't have to use `formatter` you can just call `toString()` which would allow for an answer that works with all SwiftUI versions.

```
struct VolumeSampleView: View {
    let volume = Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitVolume.liters)
    let mass = Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)
    let temp = Measurement(value: 30, unit: UnitTemperature.fahrenheit)
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(volume.converted(to: .milliliters).toString())
            Text(volume.converted(to: .fluidOunces).toString())
            Text(mass.converted(to: .grams).toString())
            Text(temp.converted(to: .celsius).toString())
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

To show locale adjusted measurements you can just add `.current` to the `Locale`

```
extension Formatter{
    static func measurement(unitOptions: MeasurementFormatter.UnitOptions? = .providedUnit, unitStyle: Formatter.UnitStyle = .short, numberStyle: NumberFormatter.Style = .decimal) -> MeasurementFormatter{
        
        let f = MeasurementFormatter()
        f.unitStyle = unitStyle
        
        if let options = unitOptions{ //Make unitOptions optional
            f.unitOptions = options
        }
        
        f.locale = .current //Add locale consideration

        let nf = NumberFormatter()
        nf.numberStyle = numberStyle
        
        f.numberFormatter = nf
        
        return f
    }
}
extension Measurement{
    func toString(unitOptions: MeasurementFormatter.UnitOptions? = .providedUnit, unitStyle: Formatter.UnitStyle = .short, numberStyle: NumberFormatter.Style = .decimal) -> String{
        
        let f = Formatter.measurement(unitOptions: unitOptions, unitStyle: unitStyle, numberStyle: numberStyle)
        return f.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Then just set the `unitOptions` argument to `nil` when you want the units to show adjusted by locale

```
Text(volume.toString(unitOptions: nil)) //Will show locale specific version
```

Comment: Thank you. This gives a great amount of control. But I was hoping to avoid doing this and using the users locale. I may end up going this route. Or just updatind to ios16. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @byrnec25 you can use the locale with this, it is a part if `MeasurementFormatter` you can just add it there with `.current` and remove the `unitOptions` because it would no longer be the provided unit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I manned up and did the work to get this working. Much appreciated. Super powerful.

Comment: @byrnec25 SwiftUI makes a lot easy it can seem daunting to jump into the nitty gritty. Don’t forget you have cmd+z and source control, it gives you a little cushion.

Comment: So is this a bug, or? I've just noticed that UnitVolume.litres is giving me cubic centimetres cm³ instead of L using Xcode 14.3 iOS 16.4 and Xcode 15 beta 8 iOS 17

Answer (score 1):

Your last attempt is close. Just change the usage to `.liquid` instead of `asProvided`.

```
Text("\(Measurement(value: Double(brew.water), unit: UnitVolume.milliliters).formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .liquid, numberFormatStyle: .number)))")
```

This gives me the result as "fl oz" with a locale of en_US.

Note that `MeasurementFormatUnitUsage<UnitVolume>.liquid` is only available as of iOS 16.0 so this solution won't work with iOS 15.

Comment: Beautiful! But.. ios16 only. Is there anything available pre ios16? Thanks for the reply!